# Sum of even numbers N?

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions, gauss-sums

To sum first N numbers we can use this formula:

$$1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n = \frac{(n  (n + 1)}{2}$$

To sum even numbers we multiply this formula by 2:

$$2 + 4 + 6 + \ldots + 2n = n (n + 1)$$

Lets check sum of even numbers until 6:

```
Sum(odd) =  2 + 4 + 6 = 12
```

Then let's use the formula: `6 * (6 + 1) = 6 * 6 + 6 = 42.`

What is wrong with formula or my calculations?

Comment: $2 + 4 + 6 = 12$ is true, but that is the sum of *even* numbers.

Comment: Do you mean even?

Comment: What you write is sum of even numbers but you can find sum of odd numbers with subtracting.

Comment: Sorry, I meant even numbers, fixed

Comment: $2 + 4 + 6 = 12 = n(n+1)$ for $n=3$, so what is the problem?

Comment: because n must be 3

Comment: So, `n` it is not last number it is amount of numbers?

Comment: As you wrote: $2 + 4 + 6 +\ldots +  2n = n  (n + 1)$. That is the sum of $n$ even numbers, and $2n$ is the last number in that sum.

Comment: Here you can find a $\LaTeX$ tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$2+4+6=12$ is the sum of the first *three* even numbers, and indeed for $n=3$ you have that $3\cdot (3+1)=12$

If you set $n=6$, you are calculating the sum of the first *six* even numbers, and indeed $2+4+6+8+10+12=42$

So, there is nothing wrong with your formula: it is correct. You just misapplied it.

Answer (score 4):

You use that

$$2+4 + 6+ \ldots + 2n = 2(1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n) = 2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = n(n+1)$$

So the $n$ used is the number of terms added, not the final term, but half of it.